# Call function from variable with NodeJS and Lambda

Tags: javascript, node.js, lambda

I'm looking to pass a variable as a function name with NodeJS in lambda as in the following.  This is part of code for accessing data within Google Sheets.

```js
async function getCellByRowAndColumnName(row_number, column_name)
{
    // Get Sheet
    const sheet = doc.sheetsById[0];
    // Get Rows
    const rows = await sheet.getRows();

    console.log(rows[row_number].column_name);
}
```

It's serverless so window doesn't work.  I wasn't able to get creating and executing a temporary function to work either.

Any ideas on a working method for this?  Much appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: If you define a method in a plain object you can then use the variable to reference that method dynamically and execute it. For instance: `const o = { f: () => {} }`. Now if I have a variable like the following: `const name = 'f';` then I can execute the method like this: `o[name]()`. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you, Abrar.  

Do you have another example with a little bit more verbosity?  I'm working on figuring this out.  When I test this out it comes out as undefined.

I'm currently looking into setting a function as a variable to see if I can execute it.  Rows[0] is an object and then .column_name is function provided by a require.